# Python - when is 'import' required?

Tags: python, import, module

mod1.py

```
import mod2

class Universe:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def answer(self):
        return 42

u = Universe()
mod2.show_answer(u)
```

mod2.py

```
#import mod1 -- not necessary
def show_answer(thing):
    print thing.answer()
```

Coming from a C++ background I had the feeling it was necessary to import the module containing the Universe class definition before the show_answer function would work. I.e. everything had to be declared before it could be used.

Am I right in thinking this isn't necessary? This is duck typing, right?  So if an import isn't required to see the methods of a class, I'd at least need it for the class definition itself and the top level functions of a module?

In one script I've written, I even went as far as writing a base class to declare an interface with a set of methods, and then deriving concrete classes to inherit that interface, but I think I get it now - that's just wrong in Python, and whether an object has  a particular method is checked at runtime at the point where the call is made?

I realise Python is *so* much more dynamic than C++, it's taken me a while to see how little code you actually need to write!

I think I know the answer to this question, but I just wanted to get clarification and make sure I was on the right track.

UPDATE: Thanks for all the answers, I think I should clarify my question now:

Does mod2.show_answer() need an import (of any description) to know that thing has a method called answer(), or is that determined dynamically at runtime?

Comment: To answer you second question: no, it's dynamic. It looks into thing.__dict__ for an "answer" entry. Grep for "Class instances" at http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import` is all about names -- mostly "bare names" that are bound at top level (AKA global level, AKA module-level names) in a certain module, say `mod2`. When you've done `import mod2`, you get the `mod2` namespace as an available name (top-level in your own module, if you're doing the `import` itself as top level, as is most common; but a local `import` within a function would make `mod2` a local variable of that function, etc); and therefore you can use `mod2.foobar` to access the name `foobar` that's bound at top level in `mod2`. If you have no need to access such names, then you have no need to `import mod2` in your own module.

Answer (score 7):

In this case you're right: show_answer() is given an object, of which it calls the method "answer". As long as the object given to show_answer() has such a method, it doesn't matter where the object comes from.

If, however, you wanted to create an instance of Universe inside mod2, you'd have to import mod1, because Universe is not in the mod2 namespace, even after mod2 has been imported by mod1.

Comment: Indeed, though there are ways around it -- a mod1 class could pass a Universe object to mod2 which could create more instances of it if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Think of import being more like the linker.
With "import mod2" you are simply telling python that it can find the function in the file mod2.py

Comment: Remember, import happens at run-time.  There is no compile time.  You don't declare everything.  You merely provide a way to resolve the names.

Comment: Is that relevant? The import is simply telling the VM which file to look in, it doesn't make any difference when it does that.

Comment: Think of import basically as combination of #include for the whole file, and change of names xxx -> mod.xxx

Comment: But - and I think this is really my question - do I need an import for show_answer to know that it's parameter has an answer() method?

Comment: @Steve, no, you can try to call any method on any object and it will succeed in that object happens to have that method for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

import in Python loads the module into the given namespace. As such, is it as if the def show_answer actually existed in the mod1.py module. Because of this, mod2.py does not need to know of the Universe class and thus you do not need to import mod1 from mod2.py.

Comment: No, it doesn't because import happens before the definition of Universe class.

Comment: I somewhat misworded what I meant, I'll correct it to what I meant to say.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in this case, importing `mod1` in `mod2.py` should **not** work.
Would it not create a circular reference?

Comment: Indeed, and see more info in the link in my answer.

Comment: Oops, yes, you're right. I trimmed down the example code a bit too much. Try to imagine that class Universe is in a module all on it's own!

Answer (score 1):

In fact,  according to [this explanation](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) , the circular `import` will not work the way you want it to work: if you uncomment `import mod1`, the second module will still not know about the `Universe`.

I think this is quite reasonable. If both of your files need access to the type of some specific object, like `Universe`, you have several choices:

- if your program is small, just use one file
- if it's big, you need to decide if your files both need to know how `Universe` is implemented, perhaps passing an object of not-yet-known type to `show_answer` is fine
- if that doesn't work for you, by all means put `Universe` in a separate module and load it first.

Comment: Yep, sorry about the circular import, that was a mistake on my part. My question was, though: is it true that mod2 *doesn't* need to know how Universe is implemented? I could just as well pass an ExamQuestion object to show_answer just so long as it has an answer() method?

Comment: Yep. So it is. I think this makes Python easier to understand. Though some people complain this makes it possible to make a mistake of calling a method on a wrong type, I have yet to see this in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about C++, so can't directly compare it, but..

`import` basically loads the other Python script (`mod2.py`) into the current script (the top level of `mod1.py`). It's not so much a link, it's closer to an `eval`

For example, in Python'ish psuedo-code:

```
eval("mod2.py")
```

is the same as..

```
from mod2 import *
```

..it executes mod2.py, and makes the functions/classes defined accessible in the current script.

Both above snippets would allow you to call `show_answer()` (well, eval doesn't quite work like that, thus I called it pseudo code!)

```
import mod2
```

..is basically the same, but instead of bringing in all the functions into the "top level", it brings them into the mod2 module, so you call `show_answer` by doing..

```
mod2.show_answer
```

> Am I right in thinking [the import in mod2.py] isn't necessary?

Absolutely. In fact if you try and import `mod1` from `mod2` you get a circular dependancy error (since `mod2` then tries to import `mod1` and so on..)